# My AngularJS app doesn't load my controller/view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple AngularJS application. When i run my app then it doesn't show the partial view that it should load in the `<ng-view>` tag.

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">
    <head>
        <title>Test!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Index!</h2>
        <ng-view></ng-view>

        <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="/App/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/App/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', ['ngRoute']);

// Routes
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', {
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            templateUrl: '/App/partials/dashboard.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ reditectTo: '/dashboard' });
}]);
```

And my `controllers.js`:

```
app.controller("DashboardController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [
      { "title": "asdf", "description": "describe" },
      { "title": "second one", "description": "second describe" },
    ];
}]);
```

When i run my app then all i get to see is the `<h2>Index!</h2>` message. Why is my `Dashboard.html` partial not loading? I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: In your app.js, you have `.otherwise({ reditectTo: '/dashboard' });`.  Is the typo in your code or just here?

Comment: @CharlesWood What typo? (it's probably in my code then)

Comment: @Vivendi Does route changes to /dashboard, when you launch your application?

Comment: I'm assuming `reditectTo` should be `redirectTo`.

Comment: Oh damn it, just noticed the typo. Yeah that was it. That was embarrassing :-x Thanks though. Guess you could put it an answer so i can accept it in a few minutes.